# Цикл в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

Таблица table, поля id (желательно не использовать его), type(тип), url(адрес). По одной предыдущей теме я научился группировать данные в таблице, добавлять их в массив. И ничего сложного с выводом... но, есть одна не реализуемая хотелка, подскажите, как реализовать такое.

Берем табличку, группируем данные по типу, и выводим - тип 1, тире, и перечисляем, все что относится к типу 1... далее тип два, и так далее... я пытался написать цикл в цикле - дальше первого цикла "комп тупит" 8-)

Подскажите, как написать?

Comment: Приведите свой цикл здесь

Comment: т.е вы хотите иметь все данные сгрупированные по типу ?

если да - то не нужно 2 цикла, просто нужно выполнять "группировку" непосредственно в php

Comment: да, нужны данные сгруппированные по типу, при чем с начала должна быть подпись, что это за тип (описал выше). если не секрет, можете мне написать пример такой группировки в php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я вас правильно понял - то как то так:

```
$res = query('select  type, url from table order by url');
$data = array();
while ($r = fetch($res)) {
    $data[$r['type']][] = $r['url'];
}

foreach ($data as $type => $urls) {
    echo $type . " - " . join(', ', $urls) . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте `order by type`, а затем при выводе проверяйте, не изменилось ли поле type по сравнению с предыдущим значением.

**Добавлен код**

```
// $ar - массив полученных данных (id, type, url)
$type = '';
$html = '';
foreach($ar as $v){
    if($v['type'] != $type){
        $html .= 'type "'.$v['type'].'":<br>';
    }
    $html .= ' - '.$v['url'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло. я аж про ORDER BY забыл, пока думал как ))